# How to save and extract custom data from streams?

Tags: c++, stream

I am saving data with `ofstream` to a ***file*** and trying to extract from it with `ifstream`.
Only the saving process works, but when I try to extract it's starting to give me garbage data.

I want to save this way using `ofstream`

```
ofstream & operator<<(ofstream &ofs, Item &i){
        ofs<<"Item name "<<i.name<<endl;
        ofs<<"Item price "<<i.price<<endl;
        ofs<<"Item quantity "<<i.qty<<endl;
        return ofs;
}
```

In the main method

```
ofstream ofs("Items.txt",ios::trunc)
vector<Item *>::iterator itr;
for(itr=list.begin(); itr!=list.end(); itr++){
          ofs<<**itr;
}
```

It's work perfectly fine when I check Items.txt.

It fails to extract using `ifstream`

```
ifstream & operator>>(ifstream &ifs, Item &i){
       ifs>>i.name>>i.price>>i.qty;
       return ifs;
}
```

I try to do this way `ifs>>"Item name ">>i.name>>endl;`
But this gave me compiler error.

In Main Method

```
Item item;
ifstream ifs("Items.txt");
ifs>>item;

for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
     cout<<item<<endl;
}
```

In case you are wondering about `cout<<item<<endl;`, I just create

```
ostream & operator<<(ostream &os, Item &i){
         os<<"Item name "<<i.name<<endl;
         os<<"Item price "<<i.price<<endl;
         os<<"Item quantity "<<i.qty<<endl;
         return os;
}
```

I don't know how to exact custom data using ifstream.

Can anyone help, thanks?

Comment: `It fails to extract using ifstream`: Is that a compilation error or a runtime error?

Comment: It's compilation error. ```exec.cpp:38:5: error: invalid operands to binary expression ('std::__1::ifstream'
      (aka 'basic_ifstream<char>') and 'const char [15]')
        ifs>>"Item qunatity ">>i.qty>>endl;
        ~~~^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

```
istream & operator>>(istream &ifs, Item &i) {
    string dummy;
    ifs >> dummy >> dummy >> i.name 
        >> dummy >> dummy >> i.price
        >> dummy >> dummy >> i.qty;
    return ifs;
}
```

The purpose of the `dummy` variable is to read (and discard) the extra labels you added to the output `Item name` etc.

If you wanted to go further you could also add checks that the extra information is as you expected and signal an error if it is not.

Note that `operator>>` should work on `istream` not `ifstream`. Some day you might want to read from some input other than a file, and since `istream` works with files and with other kinds of input there's nothing lost by using `istream`.

Similarly `operator<<` should work on `ostream` not `ofstream`.

In other words there's no need to duplicate your `operator>>` and `operator<<`, by using just `istream` and `ostream` they'll work with all kinds of input and output.

Comment: @realNameDoesn'tExist Because `Item name` is two words, and each `dummy` is going to read one word only.